# Внутренняя база данных C# приложения без установки СУБД

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Планирую сделать настольное приложение для работы с генеалогическим древом. Как я понимаю (занимаюсь C# пару месяцев, а с базами данных почти не работала, поэтому опыта не имею), для хранения данных о членах лучше использовать БД, но тут встаёт вопрос, связанный с конкретикой.  Сторонние СУБД могут и не стоять на устройстве пользователя (могу ошибаться, поэтому, прошу, если что, поправьте), а просить его что-либо устанавливать, возможно, не самая лучшая идея.
На глаза попался Sqlite, и хотелось бы знать:

1. Хорошая ли идея использовать Sqlite для подобных целей?
2. Когда появляется большой смысл использовать MySQl/PostgreSQL/MS SQL? Если предполагается одновременный доступ нескольких пользователей? Большие объёмы данных?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: `Хорошая ли идея использовать Sqlite для подобных целей?` Да, если база данных локальная, расположена рядом с приложением в виде файла. `Когда появляется большой смысл использовать MySQl/PostgreSQL/MS SQL?` когда требуется высокопроизводительный конкурентный доступ к базе, например на веб-сервере.

Comment: Мой вам совет, посмотрите в сторону [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/). Ну а так, все зависит от конкретно ваших потребностей, ибо если у вас данных будет не так много, чтение/запись не так часто, то можно и вовсе обойтись сериализацией в JSON/XML и др. форматы, без использования сторонних библиотек и прочих механизмов.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - LiteDB имеет много [недостатков](https://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/8079852?tree=tree).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - спасибо за чёткое обозначение недостатков. Просто если бы я сам пробовал - на то, чтобы их найти ушло бы много времени :-)

Comment: @S.H. - я тоже немного щупал LiteDB. И был рад, когда наткнулся на то обсуждение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, только не стоит забывать, что все зависит от конкретной цели, задач. По ссылки я, к примеру вижу, что используют LiteDB для сервера, как по мне, это странное решение (как, собственно, и SQLite), ибо они не особо годятся для этих целей. Минус? Ну, не назвал бы. Вот допустим есть проект, где надо хранить небольшое число данных с удобном доступом к ним (скажем, настройки проекта, ведение журнала, кэширование, список файлов и др.), то есть задачи, где можно обойтись простым JSON. И что, хотите сказать, эти все "минусы" испортят опыт работы в данном проекте? Не думаю...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - отчасти я согласен. Но в том-то и дело, что для настроек вполне хватит json-файла. А СУБД нужна для больших объёмов данных со сложными связями между ними и быстрым поиском. Тут-то litedb и может подложить свинью.

Comment: В целом, я бы рекомендовал автору реализовать приложение в нескольких вариантах. В одном использовать sqlite, в другом - litedb, в третьем - просто файлы (можно и четвёртый, и пятый вариант: xml, json, бинарные форматы). Таким образом будет получен опыт работы с реляционной СУБД, с NoSql БД, и с файлами разных форматов. А как это сделать, не переписывая приложение полностью? На помощь приходят паттерны и методологии разработки: репозиторий, абстракции, инъекция зависимостей и пр. После завершения проекта автора можно будет посвятить минимум в мидлы (или направить в дурку).

Answer (score 1):

## База Данных только на XML.

Самый простой способ - использовать DataTable из пространства System.Data и XML.
Пример создания базы данных, добавления записи и сохранения.

```
    private void InitData()
    {
    DataSet dsUsers = new DataSet("Users");
    DataTable UsersDataTable = dsUsers.Tables.Add("UsersTable");
    string _FilePathUsersXML = @"C:\\AuthorizationList.XML";
    if (File.Exists(_FilePathUsersXML))
    {
    XmlReadMode v = UsersDataTable.ReadXml(_FilePathUsersXML);
    //Debug.WriteLine(UsersDataTable.Rows.Count);
    }
    else
    {
    DataColumn c = UsersDataTable.Columns.Add("FULLNAME", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    c.AllowDBNull = false;
    c.Unique = true;
    c.ReadOnly = false;

    c = UsersDataTable.Columns.Add("NAME", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    c.AllowDBNull = false;
    c.Unique = true;
    c.ReadOnly = false;

    c = UsersDataTable.Columns.Add("PASSWORD", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    c.AllowDBNull = false;
    c.Unique = false;
    c.ReadOnly = false;
    }
    }

    // Add new row:
    UsersDataTable.Rows.Add("Full Name", "FN", "1234");

    // Save to XML:
    static void SaveUsersDataTable()
    {
        UsersDataTable.AcceptChanges();
        UsersDataTable.WriteXml(_FilePathUsersDataTable, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
```

Comment: тут стоит отметить общую проблему хранения через сериализацию: файл читается и записывается полностью. для конфига - это неплохо, а вот изменение небольших кусочков будет неэффективно. плюс реализация фишек бд (блокировки на запись, индексы, транзакции и др) ложится на ваши плечи.

Comment: Если размер xml файла меньше 100мб, а запись происходит не чаще 1 раза в час - то вполне терпимо. Если чаще/больше - то это мазохизму подобно. Так-же не забываем что запись в файл может закончиться фейлом, особенно если база portable на флешке, и нужно руками делать бекапы.